# How to send multiple (list) json objects inside text file to run 'ab' load test POST request?

Tags: python, http, apachebench

I would like to send multiple POST requests with multiple json objects inside text file to the python server using apache bench load test tool.

```
ab -p sample.txt -T application/json -c 2 -n 4 http://localhost:8080/xxxx
```

If sample.txt contains single instance of json, it works fine

```
{"first_name":"Clara","last_name":"Gislason"}
```

however when sample.txt contains list of json objects as below, it doesn't work.

```
[{"first_name":"Clara","last_name":"Gislason"},{"first_name":"Meaghan","last_name":"Jenkins"}]
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What do you want to do? calling this endpoint with different sample requests? If you want to use the new content of sample.txt as the request body, there shouldn't be a problem as long as your backend support this schema.